# HTML. Замена изображения при наведении на ссылку

Tags: php, javascript, css3, html5

При наведеении на ссылку, должна подгружаться другая картинка в замен cart.png. Это возможно? Подойдет вариант и не на чистом html+css. Естественно, это должно происходить без перезагрузки страницы.

```
  <div class="v_korziny">
        <img src="img/cart.png">
        <a href="#">В корзину</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.v_korziny a').addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
  document.querySelector('.v_korziny img').src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/bd6b85/000000.png"
});
document.querySelector('.v_korziny a').addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
  document.querySelector('.v_korziny img').src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/6b83bd/000000.png"
})
```

```html
<div class="v_korziny"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/6b83bd/000000.png" alt="" /><a href="#">В корзину</a></div>
```

Comment: Работает. Но только для первого такого блока в верстке. У меня несколько абсолютно таких же блоков с такими же классами. Как применить это сразу ко всем таким блокам?

Comment: Ну так код то надо было приводить тот, что у Вас. Мы ведь не экстрасенсы )) Предоставьте либо код страницы, либо класс\идентификатор\уникальный_атрибут родителя этих элементов

Comment: Тупо копипаст моего кода, что я написал выше, 8 раз)

Comment: При обращении к DOM - нужно знать как дерево было построено! Да блин, лень спорить.))  Рабочий вариант ниже. Расширяйте по аналогии.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let parent=document.querySelector('.parent'),
    arrImgReserve = ['https://dummyimage.com/100x100/647fd9/000000.png',
                     'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/68d99f/000000.png',
                     'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/d99568/000000.png'],
    arrImgOrig = ['https://dummyimage.com/100x100/db6498/000000.png',
                  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/66d3d9/000000.png',
                  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/d0d968/000000.png'];

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.v_korziny>a'),(e,i)=>{
  e.previousElementSibling.dataset.imageOriginal=arrImgOrig[i];
  e.previousElementSibling.dataset.imageReserve=arrImgReserve[i]});

parent.addEventListener('mouseover',e=>{
  if (e.target.classList.contains('linkHover')) {
    e.target.previousElementSibling.src=e.target.previousElementSibling.dataset.imageReserve
  }
});
parent.addEventListener('mouseout',e=>{
  if (e.target.classList.contains('linkHover')) {
    e.target.previousElementSibling.src=e.target.previousElementSibling.dataset.imageOriginal
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="v_korziny"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/db6498/000000.png" alt="" /><a class="linkHover" href="#">В корзину</a></div>
  <div class="v_korziny"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/66d3d9/000000.png" alt="" /><a class="linkHover" href="#">В корзину</a></div>
  <div class="v_korziny"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/d0d968/000000.png" alt="" /><a class="linkHover" href="#">В корзину</a></div>
</div>
```